# When opening a csv in Excel, the data is displayed wrong

Tags: php, excel, csv

When I export an excel table with the standard php csv lib and open it in libre office, everything looks fine.

However, if I open it in Microsoft Excel, everything is always in column A.
One container takes `name,beschreibung,preis,preiseinheit,bilder`

Do you have an idea what causes this and how to fix this?

Comment: Are you using a `;` separator or a `,`? To load automatically (double click on the file) MS Excel requires the appropriate separator based on it's locale, so it isn't consistent; but you can always open MS Excel and then import the file, which allows you to specify the separator that it should expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Excel will automatically detect some cvs formats, if your file does not match what Excel expects, you have to do this additional manual step:

- Select the A columns with all your data
- Go to Data > Text to Columns
- Separated Data
- select whatever separator you use (coma, it seems)
- Finalize

This should get you the format you need.